# RewriteRule in htaccess does not work correct

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to rewrite old URLs like this:

Old URL:

`http://www.domain.de/index.php?id=189&ext[stars]=PvVYdx58CfBpEIcUsdDvuE4fsvnwHw`

New URL:

`http://www.domain.de/sub1/sub2/stars/PvVYdx58CfBpEIcUsdDvuE4fsvnwHw`

So I built following rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&ext\[stars\]=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/sub1/sub2/stars/%2? [L,R=301]
```

but it does not work, the redirect happens to `http://www.domain.de/sub1/sub2` without adding the parameter.

Any hints how to get this working?

Comment: You say, you want to rewrite, but the rule does a redirect. Which one do you want?

Comment: a redirect, which is a rewrite as well :-) You see it in the rule (R=301)

Comment: The rule looks good and it does work as tested on my system. Restart your browser, clear the cache, and: Never test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!